# Не появляется плавающая шапка

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть шапка,которая не отображается. Работаю с инструментом fullpage.js. Может у кого-нибудь была такая проблема. Сайт прилагается http://l37-195-222-8.novotelecom.ru/

```css
.header{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 72px;
line-height: 108px;
height: 108px;
background: #335C7D;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
<h1>Прикреплённая шапка сайта</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: z-index: 99999;

Comment: @programmer403 ну зачем так много, z-index: 2; полностью хватит))

Comment: @Arendach не хватало для комментария)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно присвоить шапке индекс больше.

`z-index: 99999;`